# Joomla and heterogeneous databases

Tags: c#, php, web-services, joomla

I am designing an internal utility web application for the team.

The front-end will be `PHP` based on `Joomla` so it will take care of user-authentication and all `CMS` stuff.

The back-end databases are varied: `Excel`, `MS Access`, `MSSQL`. Therefore I wish to build a `C#`-based web services which wraps the business logic and data access.

Modules in Joomla will be built which call the web services and presents the data in HTML.

Would it be a good idea? If it is, are there any existing libraries or framework that can facilitate?

Many thanks

Comment: No reason at all that it wouldn't work. You can look at some of the API packages (e.g. github, mediawiki) to see how they work and model it on that.